# Django: Alert the user that he hasn't yet completed something specific in the app

Tags: python, django, profile

I would like to create a feature that alerts the user that he has not completed his profile.
Just like it is on LinkedIn.
Any ideas how to do this in Django?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jinja(I mean if you use backend render).
You can write a middleware to fill some `view.context` about that.

If you use Django Rest Framework, you just need write a Viewset about profile. and render that in fornt-end.

*Jinja is a template package. Django template use Jinja to render.*